# How to implement APP_USER variable in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a teacher table that stores a teacher username, password, id and other things. I have a course creation page and a teacher details page. Currently, when a teacher logs in with their username and password and clicks on the teacher details page, they can see every other teachers details including their own and can edit every teachers details. I want to allow the teacher to only edit and see their details. I know this will involve using the app_user variable but i have no idea how to implement this (would it be a dynamic action or computation). I also dont know what sql expression i would write. If someone could list the steps to do this and the type of code i would need to write that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :APP_USER as shown below

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE user_id = :APP_USER
```

Below link helps you to learn more about it.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#BEIHCJBG

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this query in your teacher details region

```
select * from teacher_details where user_name = :APP_USER;
```

for more details https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#BEIHCJBG